# Data from room database does not show up on real phone

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am creating an app called MotoDescriptive and i'm using a **ROOM** database in order to store my data (names, descriptions and urls of motorcycles). Everything was working perfectly fine on my emulator but yesterday i tried to run the app on my phone and the recyclerview was completely blank probably due to an empty database. You can check my code down below and thanks in advance.

Here is my *AppDatabase.java* file

```
package com.example.motodescriptive;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;
import androidx.room.migration.Migration;
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;

@Database(entities = {MotoEntity.class}, version = 14)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static AppDatabase instance;
    private static String NAME = "moto-database";
    public abstract MotoDao motoDao();


    public static synchronized AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, NAME).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().allowMainThreadQueries().addMigrations(MIGRATION_13_14).build();

        }
        return instance;


    }

    static final Migration MIGRATION_13_14 = new Migration(13, 14) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

        }
    };

}
```

*MotoDao.java* file

```
package com.example.motodescriptive;

import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Update;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface MotoDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM motoentity")
    List<MotoEntity> selectAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM motoentity WHERE moto_name LIKE :name")
    List<MotoEntity> checkForName(String name);

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM motoentity where moto_name = :name")
    int agentsCount(String name);

    @Insert
    void insert(MotoEntity motoEntity);

    @Update
    void update(MotoEntity motoEntity);

    @Delete
    void delete(MotoEntity motoEntity);

    @Query("DELETE FROM motoentity where ID = :motoid")
    void deleteById(int motoid);





}
```

**MotoEntity.java** file

```
package com.example.motodescriptive;


import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
public class MotoEntity implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int ID;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "moto_name")
    public String moto_name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "moto_desc")
    public String moto_desc;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "moto_longdesc")
    public String moto_longdesc;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "moto_longdesc2")
    public String moto_longdesc2;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "moto_longdesc3")
    public String moto_longdesc3;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "moto_longdesc4")
    public String moto_longdesc4;

    public String getMoto_longdesc2() {
        return moto_longdesc2;
    }

    public void setMoto_longdesc2(String moto_longdesc2) {
        this.moto_longdesc2 = moto_longdesc2;
    }

    public String getMoto_longdesc3() {
        return moto_longdesc3;
    }

    public void setMoto_longdesc3(String moto_longdesc3) {
        this.moto_longdesc3 = moto_longdesc3;
    }

    public String getMoto_longdesc4() {
        return moto_longdesc4;
    }

    public void setMoto_longdesc4(String moto_longdesc4) {
        this.moto_longdesc4 = moto_longdesc4;
    }

    public String getMoto_longdesc() {
        return moto_longdesc;
    }

    public void setMoto_longdesc(String moto_longdesc) {
        this.moto_longdesc = moto_longdesc;
    }

    @ColumnInfo(name = "moto_img")
    public String moto_img;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getMoto_name() {
        return moto_name;
    }

    public void setMoto_name(String moto_name) {
        this.moto_name = moto_name;
    }

    public String getMoto_desc() {
        return moto_desc;
    }

    public void setMoto_desc(String moto_desc) {
        this.moto_desc = moto_desc;
    }

    public String getMoto_img() {
        return moto_img;
    }

    public void setMoto_img(String moto_img) {
        this.moto_img = moto_img;
    }
}
```

And finally this is where i added my data from the DB to an arraylist which i passed to the adapter.
**I web scraped my data and added it to the database. Since i don’t need that part of code again because it is already stored in the DB, i deleted it.**

```
List<MotoEntity> motorcycles = appDatabase.motoDao().selectAll();
        
        adapter = new MotorAdapter((ArrayList<MotoEntity>) motorcycles, this, getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Comment: You should refine your answer. It is too broad and filled with unnecessary details. Try to create hardcoded MotoEntity with its constructor and display it to eliminate the possible problems in the adapter. Then display `agentsCount` value somewhere to check that the DB is not empty.

Comment: The data in your database is only stored locally. So right now the data is stored on the emulated device (your PC). When you run the app on your phone there is nothing in the database because, like you said, you deleted the code you used to initially populate the database. You need to populate the database with data on every device you run it on.